# Textbox Visible based on Dropdownlist Selected Item without javascript

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

How to display textbox only when a particular item is selected from Dropdownlist in vb.net without javascript

Comment: Can you understand your own question? I can't. Have you tried anything? If so, show it. It might clarify your requirement and the problem you had.

Comment: I guess you are looking for `DropDownList_SelectedChange` event, you can simply show and hide your textbox based on selected value. But IMO it's always better to do such stuffs at client side.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would put this in a [DropDownList.OnSelectedIndexChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) Event Handler, but it should also work in Page_Load:

```
If Not ddlYourDropDownList.SelectedValue Is Nothing AndAlso ddlYourDropDownList.SelectedValue = "YourParticularSelection" Then

    txtYourTextbox.Visible = True

Else

    txtYourTextbox.Visible = False

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you mentioned Javascript as that is a separate language from VB.NET.

To address your question, as Rahul Singh mentioned, you would put code in the `DropDownList_SelectedIndexChange` event and would show or hide each item based on the conditions you require. Here's an example:

```
Private Sub DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged
        If DropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0 Then 'corresponds to the first option
            TextBox1.Show()
        ElseIf DropDownList.SelectedIndex = 1 Then 'corresponds to the second option
            TextBox1.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub
```

You would also probably want to set the `TextBox1`'s `Hidden` property to `True` in the Visual Studio Design View so that it doesn't show when the form starts up and will only show when the user changes the `DropDownList`.